# Correct way to handle UserControl properties?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

In my Windows Store App, I have a CueAnswerButton user control. It contains an Image control which binds to `{Binding NormalImage}` in the view model. However I have other controls and properties inside CueAnswerButton which need to be updated whenever the bound property changes (I want to execute code inside CueAnswerButton whenever it changes).

How can I do so?

I have found [other articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) that explain something similar, but not quite.  Perhaps I don't know the right terminology to use to find the answer.

Thanks for your help.

```
// View data model for a cue answer button.

public class CueAnswerViewData : DependencyObject
{
  public CueAnswerViewData()
  {
  }

  public const string NormalImagePropertyTag = "NormalImageProperty";
  public static readonly DependencyProperty NormalImageProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register(
         NormalImagePropertyTag,
         typeof(ImageSource),
         typeof(CueAnswerViewData),
         new PropertyMetadata(null));
  public ImageSource NormalImage
  {
    get
    {
      return (ImageSource)GetValue(
        NormalImageProperty);
    }
    set
    {
      SetValue(NormalImageProperty, value);
    }
  }
```

and the CueAnswerButton.xaml:

```
  <Grid>
    <Button x:Name="m_button" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            BorderThickness="0"
            />

    <Image x:Name="m_image" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
           Stretch="Fill"
           Source="{Binding NormalImage}" 
           />

    ...
```

Basically I want to call CueAnswerButton.updateSkinnableProperties() whenever the NormalImage property on the ViewData changes. Yes this is a port of a wp7 app :), and it is still a work in progress.

```
private void updateSkinnableProperties()
{
  bool skinned = isSkinned();

  m_image.IsHitTestVisible = skinned;
  m_button.IsHitTestVisible = !skinned;

  Background = m_correctHint ? m_correctAnswerGreenBrush : null;
  m_textbox.Background = m_correctHint ? m_correctAnswerGreenBrush : null;
  m_button.Background = m_correctHint ? m_correctAnswerGreenBrush : 
    m_phoneBackgroundBrush;

  m_button.BorderThickness = (skinned || m_correctHint) ?
    m_zeroThickness : m_phoneBorderThickness;

  m_textbox.Foreground = (skinned || m_correctHint) ?
    m_blackBrush : m_phoneForegroundBrush;

  m_button.Padding = skinned ?
    m_zeroThickness : m_phoneTouchTargetOverhang;

  if (!skinned)
  {
    m_button.Content = null;
  }

  updateSkinnableStateBasedProperties();
}

public bool isSkinned()
{
  bool skinned = false;

  if (m_normalImage != null && m_normalImage.ToString().Length > 0)
  {
    skinned = true;
  }

  return skinned;
}

private void updateSkinnableStateBasedProperties()
{
  if (!m_correctHint && isSkinned())
  {
    m_image.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    if (m_pressed && m_pressedImage != null)
    {
      m_image.Source = m_pressedImage;
    }
    else
    {
      m_image.Source = m_normalImage;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    m_image.Source = null;

    if(!m_correctHint)
    {
      m_textbox.Foreground = m_pressed ?
        m_phoneBackgroundBrush : m_phoneForegroundBrush;

      m_button.Background = m_pressed ?
        m_phoneForegroundBrush : m_phoneBackgroundBrush;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving +1's to Jeff Brand, as his answers helped me find my solution. However, the best way to solve this was to stop trying to fight the system and move the updateSkinnableProperties() logic into the ViewModel itself, and have it implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Some of the properties it exposes are more UI-centric rather than Data-centric (such as Brush and Thickness properties), but ultimately this was the cleanest and best solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a delegate that gets called everytime the DependecyProperty changes value...

```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty NormalImageProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register(
         NormalImagePropertyTag,
         typeof(ImageSource),
         typeof(CueAnswerViewData),
         new PropertyMetadata(null, (s, e) =>
                var ctrl = s as CueAnswerViewData;
                if (ctrl != null) {
                   ctrl.somePropertyToUpdate = 123;
                }
            })
            );
```

Comment: Thanks but isn't it bad design for the view model to know about the view type?

Comment: Oppps sorry.  Forgot we were talking about a view model.  In the CueAnswerButton, couldn't you just bind the other controls to NormalImage as well to react to the updated property or am I missing something?

Comment: Not easily, because I would need to write complex converters for everything. I'll update the question with this code in a sec so you know what I mean. I could define some interface such as ICueAnswerNormalImageChanged, derive my CueAnswerButton class from it, and use your solution above. But it seems as though there should be a way to do it with existing mechanisms? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Why not implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the view model.  The user control can bind to the PropertyChanged event for the view model (assuming you are assigning it to the DataContext) and monitor for property changes?  View Models usually implement INotifyPropertyChanged and not DepedencyObject.  Trying to fire off answers quick since I am in the middle of something... sorry if I am missing something.